# Effectively merge big parquet files

Tags: hadoop, parquet

I'm using parquet-tools to merge parquet files. But it seems that parquet-tools needs an amount of memory as big as the merged file. Do we have other ways or configurable options in parquet-tools to use memory more effectively? Cause I run the merge job in as a map job on hadoop env. And the container gets killed every time cause it used more memory than it is provided.

Thank you.

Comment: Try Spark, Pig, or Hive?

Comment: Why do you want to merge Parquet files? This is a serious question you will need to answer (at least to yourself) as normally all tools that deal with Parquet files, can read multiple files as they were one.

Comment: @xhochy we stores them in HDFS, and a lot of files is generated everyday. And hdfs cant handle that well, so it is better when we merge them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend using parquet-tools merge, since it just places row groups one after the another, so you will still have small groups, just packed together in a single file. The resulting file will typically not have noticably better performance, and under certain circumstances it may even perform worse than separate files. See [PARQUET-1115](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-1115) for details.

Currently the only proper way to merge Parquet files is to read all data from them and write it to a new Parquet file. You can do it with a MapReduce job (requires writing custom code for this purpose) or using Spark, Hive or Impala.

Answer (score 0):

If peak memory usage is a primary concern, the [***joinem***](https://github.com/mmore500/joinem) CLI might be a good fit to your use case

*joinem* wraps [polars](https://pola.rs) code implementing *lazily streamed*
I/O in order to give good performance when **working with numerous, large files**.
That means file contents don't need to be in memory all at once.

### Example Usage

Pass input files via stdin and output file as an argument.

```bash
ls -1 path/to/*.parquet | python3 -m joinem out.parquet
```

You can add the `--progress` flag to get a progress bar.

### Installation

*joinem* is available via PyPi: `python3 -m pip install joinem`.

*disclosure*: I am the library author of *joinem*.