# Trying to merge 6000 small parquet files into a single parquet file

Tags: merge, parquet

I have 6000 parquet files (5-15 kb each) in hdfs, which is creating that many tasks of spark. I need to merge them in a single file.

I have already tried below codes. The problem with the first one is it is generating a text file and I need a parquet file as output.

The issue with the second one is it works fine with 300-400 files but gives an error as "Too many files open" when I try for 6000 files.

1.)

```
hadoop jar \
 hadoop-streaming-3.2.0.jar \
-Dmapred.reduce.tasks=1 \
-Dmapred.job.queue.name=queue \
-Dstream.reduce.output=parquet \
-input "input file" \
-output "output file" \
-mapper cat \
-reducer cat
```

2.)

```
hadoop jar parquet-tools-1.9.0.jar merge /inputfile /outputfile
```

So, any help is appreciated here.

Comment: I do not recommend using `parquet-tools merge`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50395815/ for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the open file limit to 6000 in your OS.
Check:
ulimit -a | grep open

limit is configured here
/etc/security/limits.conf

Comment: Thanks... is there no other commands? or jar file available? I can't change the conf file

Comment: @NAMITASHARMa Why don't ou merge as many as you can and then run the merge again? This is not the best option but if you are limited in the OS access then this maybe a workaround