# Is there an efficient way to merge parquet files?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, parquet

**Context:**

I understand there has been a question that was asked approximately 4 years ago about this:

[Effectively merge big parquet files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50299815/effectively-merge-big-parquet-files)

**Question:**

However, I was wondering if there are any good solutions out there to merge large and numerous amount of parquet files into 1 file beside provisioning a large Spark job to read then write?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Leaving delta api aside, there is no such changed, newer approach. The Spark approach read in and write out still applies.

One must be careful, as the small files problem is an issue for csv and loading, but once data is at rest, file skipping, block skipping and such is more aided by having more than just a few files.

Comment: Delta Lake is using parquet files as well I think, which still has e.g. the small files problem. The main problem I am thinking about is to reduce total parquet file count.

Comment: Delta manages this as well, and you do not want only big files with delta, but the answer says leaving Delta format to one side, then the answer is valid. I am working with Delta lake as data architect now.

Answer (score 0):

I chimed in on the original post linked above, but to follow up here too -- the [***joinem***](https://github.com/mmore500/joinem) CLI might be a good fit to your use case, particularly if performance/peak memory use is a concern.

Under the hood, *joinem* delegates to [polars](https://pola.rs) code, which has good performance when **working with numerous, large files**.
The underlying implementation is **lazily streamed** so that file contents don't need to be in memory all at once.

### API

```bash
ls -1 folder/*.parquet | python3 -m joinem out.parquet
```

Input files should be provided via stdin (one per line) and the output file should be given as an argument.

### Installation

*joinem* is a PyPi package, installable in the usual way: `python3 -m pip install joinem`.

*disclosure*: I am the library author of *joinem*.